# Spring STS won't debug

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-tool-suite

I have a problem starting my spring java application in debug mode in spring sts.

I can run it in normal mode just fine, but when i try to debug, it gets stuck at

> 10:11:22.201 | [localhost-startStop-1] | DEBUG |
>   c.h.c.s.setup.PlatformLoggingFilter - Filter 'platformLoggingFilter'
>   configured successfully

The next step should be :

> 10:11:31.603 | [restartedMain] | INFO  |
>   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8181"]

I remember clicking something around the debug button and a small watch appeared and started counting down to 0. It vanished when it reached 0.

I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

But it never happens. Please help.

Comment: does the integrated debugger connect to that running app? If so, maybe there is a breakpoint being hit or the debugger is configured to stop automatically at uncaught exceptions (maybe there is one thrown under the hood somewhere). Just guessing a bit. If you have a sample project that reproduces this, you could file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and link to it, so that we can try to reproduce this.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong - it tries to run the application on localhost:some_random_port instead of my designated one. Does anyone know how to change that ? I tried changing properties files and adding a value to 'Debug Options' but it didn't work.

Comment: I re-installed and imported the project again. It fixed the problem.

Comment: Good news, glad to hear you got it fixed. In case you want to set specific properties for a Spring Boot app for a specific local launch only, you can define properties in the Spring Boot App launch config easy. There is a table that lets you define properties for that specific launch config, including nice content-assist, etc.